# CV2 add 2 images without transparency Python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I'm working on an image processing project. I have 2 RGB images and I would like to create a new one by overlapping the 2 input images.

This is my 2 input images:

[image: Crack] [image]

I'm using the cv2 "add" method to achieve this. But the result is not the hoped result...

The result is as follows:

[image]

I don't want to have a transparency on my red stripe. I would like something opaque, which covers the crack on the image 1.

There is my code:

```
img1 = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\francois.bock\Desktop\crack.jpg")
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img2 = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\francois.bock\Desktop\line.png")
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Adding two images
add = cv2.add(img1, img2)

#Display the image
img = PImage.fromarray(add)
img.show()
```

I also naively tried to add the 2 images like that:

```
add = img1 + img2
add = add.astype(np.uint8)
```

But the result is even stranger.

I also used the cv2 "addWeighted" method, but it also gives a transparent stripe.

So my question is, is there a simple way to add 2 images without transparency? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with straight Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

a = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
b = cv2.imread('b.png') 

# Make "a" red anywhere b>0
a[ np.any(b>0,axis=-1) ] = [0,0,255]
```

[image]

If you happen to have blue and green or any other colour lines lurking in your image too, you can use this:

```
# Anywhere image "b" is not black, use image "b", else use image "a"
result = np.where(np.any(b>0,axis=-1,keepdims=True), b, a)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. It's working, but in some cases I have a blue and a red stripe on the same image. So I don't think Numpy would be ok for cases like this

Comment: Aha! The value of a representative image in a question :-) I am updating my answer...